# How to properly code ViewController segue after implementing DetailViewConroller to use SFSafariViewController

Tags: swift

I have implemented SFSafariViewController in my DetailVC that includes textView, labels, and a button. The button when clicked opens a url.  The problem that I am having is; when the button is clicked, it opens in SFSafariVC for a second and reverts to the original webView look.  Do I need to add some code to the viewController that controls the segue to the DetailVC? As it does not address the SFSafariVC or is it suppose too?  Not sure how to proceed? I ask a lot of questions but still learning how to code correctly.

I have searched and can't find an answer.

//Here is the code on the viewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedState = selectedStates[indexPath.section]
    let state = selectedState.states[indexPath.row]
    youselectedState = state

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "AgreementDetails", sender: nil)
  }
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AgreementDetails"{
      let StateDetailVC = segue.destination as! StateDetailViewController
      StateDetailVC.state = youselectedState
    }
   }
  }
```

// Here is the code for the detailVC where I added the SFSafariVC.

```
import SafariServices
import UIKit

class StateDetailViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {


  @IBAction func watchButtonTapped(_ sender: SAButton) {
      if let url = URL(string: self.state!.url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
        self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        safariVC.delegate = self
      }
  }
  @IBOutlet weak var stateTitleTextLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stateDetailTextTitleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stateDescriptionTextView: UITextView!

  var state: State?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  title = "Reciprocal Details"

    stateTitleTextLabel.text = state?.title
    stateDetailTextTitleLabel.text = state?.detailText
    stateDescriptionTextView.text = state?.description

  func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
      controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`? This would open the URL (probably in Safari, but not a SafariViewController) before creating and presenting the SafariViewController.

Comment: How would you suggest that I code it?  I am new at coding and learning

Comment: Remove the line `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`.

Comment: Outstanding!  Works Great!